# Как создать двумерный расширяемый динамический массив

Tags: c, динамические-массивы, realloc

Целый день пытаюсь создать двумерный массив, который расширялся бы по мере заполнения (т.е. с помощью realloc). Но программа все время вылетает с ошибкой. Методом тыка определил, что ошибка возникает из-за того, что я пытаюсь расширить массив, который относится к адрессу a[msize]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {

char c;
int sum = 0;
int msize = 0;
int nsize = 0;
int **a;

a = (int**)realloc(a,(msize + 1) * sizeof(int*));

while ((c = getchar()) != '.' && c != EOF) 
{
    if(isdigit(c)) 
        sum = sum*10 + c - '0';
    else if (c == ' ') 
    {
        a[msize] = (int*)realloc(a[msize], (nsize + 1)*sizeof(int));
        a[msize][nsize++] = sum;
        sum = 0;
    }

    else if (c == ',') 
    {
        nsize = 0;
        msize++;
        a = (int**)realloc(a,(msize + 1)*sizeof(int*));
    }
}



getchar();
return 0;
```

}

Попробовал и через malloc выполнить задачу. Та же история! :(

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {

char c;
int sum = 0;
int msize = 0;
int nsize = 0;
int **a;

a = (int**)malloc(1000 * sizeof(int*));

while ((c = getchar()) != '.' && c != EOF) 
{
    if(isdigit(c)) 
        sum = sum*10 + c - '0';
    else if (c == ' ') 
    {
        a[msize] = (int*)realloc(a[msize], (nsize + 1)*sizeof(int));
        a[msize][nsize++] = sum;
        sum = 0;
    }
    else if (c == ',') 
    {
        nsize = 0;
        msize++;
    }
}
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: после `a = (int**)realloc(a,(msize + 1)*sizeof(int*));` нечего перераспределять. В `a[msize]` не будет/может не быть указателя на существующий массив.

Comment: `int **a = NULL;`

Comment: То есть мы просто выделили память, но массив все еще  никуда не ссылается - следовательно, нам нечего расширять.. Попробовал mallocom... все равно не получается(

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что после `a = malloc(1000 * sizeof(int *))` `a[i]` неопределенно для всех `i`, но ваш код предполагает, что `a[msize] == NULL` во время первого вызова `realloc(a[msize], (nsize + 1) * sizeof(int))`, a `realloc` ведёт себя как `malloc` только если адрес равен `NULL`.

Самый простой способ решить этот вопрос это сразу инициализировать `a`:

```
// ...
// a = (int**)malloc(1000 * sizeof(int*));
a = calloc(1000 * sizeof(int *));
// ...
```

> The calloc() function allocates memory for an array of nmemb elements
>   of size bytes each and returns a pointer to the allocated memory. **The
>   memory is set to zero**.

Но это явно не оптимальное решение, гораздо лучше использовать `malloc` при первой инициализации `a[msize]`:

```
//...
else if (c == ' ') {
    a[msize] = (nsize) ?
        realloc(a[msize], (nsize + 1)*sizeof(int)) :
        malloc(sizeof(int));
    a[msize][nsize++] = sum;
    sum = 0;
}
//...
```